# Returning 24+ hours in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, function, select, timestamp

Alright... I have here a query that calculates a server uptime and sometimes this uptime goes over 24 hours. I use basically

```
select start, end, start-end as real_uptime from uptime
```

`start` and `end` being `timestamp with timezone` fields

Also, I have a stored function that sums all the `real_uptime` for a period and returns them...

However, I dumped the values `start` and `end` and put them into a spreadsheet and, doing the calculations there, the results had gone differently from what the stored function processed (the stored function returned lower values). I think that he ignores results for `real_uptime` bigger than one day. Postgresql shows them as `x days hh:mm:ss`... And I want them as `hh:mm:ss` (representing the total uptime in hours, **without** the full days counting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can `extract` the `epoch` from timestamps: the seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. With those values you can easily construct your desired output:

```
SELECT "start", "end", format('%s:%s:%s', 
         (up_secs / 3600)::int::text,                       -- hours
         lpad(((up_secs % 3600) / 60)::int::text, 2, '0'),  -- minutes
         lpad((up_secs % 60)::text, 2, '0')) AS uptime      -- seconds
FROM (
  SELECT "start", "end",
         (extract(epoch from "end") - extract(epoch from "start")) AS up_secs
  FROM uptime) sub;
```

The `lpad()` function makes the minutes and seconds always two characters wide.